# How i will get model name in admin change_list_result.html

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

Does anyone know how to get the name of the model like `verbose_name` in the template from admin "change_list_result.html"?

It is necessary to get the name of the model inside the admin template `change_list.html`or`change_list_result.html`. And pass this name to JavaScript code in the same template.

The only place where I could get an approximate name of the model is an `{{app_label}}`, but there comes along with it another text, so it needs processing.

The question is how to get the model name in `change_list.html` or `change_list_result.html` in another way?

Comment: So you want to edit the `change_list_result.html`?

Comment: Willem Van Onsem Yes, I have a small script inside, in which I need to transfer a string with the name of the model that is now displayed in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long evening of brute force and a day of reading technical literature helped solve the problem.

You can get the required name like this: `{{cl.opts.verbose_name_plural | capfirst}}`

Enjoy)